# Proving that the mapping $ (Ff)(t): C[0, 1] \to C[0, 1] $ is a contraction

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1804319/341404). I tried to use [John Ma's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1804347/341404) answer, but couldn't solve this.

I need to prove that $F : C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ is a contraction mapping. $ F $ is defined as follows

$$(Fx) (t) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} x(3t) + \frac{1}{2},& 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{3}\\\ f(t), & \frac{1}{3} < t\leq \frac{2}{3}\\\ \frac{1}{2}x(3t - 2) - \frac{1}{2},&\frac{2}{3} < t \leq 1 \end{cases}
$$

Here $f(t) $ is the equation of the straight line that passes through $(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2}x(1) + \frac{1}{2})$ and $(\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{2} x(0) - \frac{1}{2})$.

Considering the metric is $d(x, y) = \sup_{t\in [0,1]} |x(t) - y(t)|$, the proof will need to show that

$$
0 \leq \sup_{t \in [0, 1]} | Fg(t) -  Fh(t) | < \sup_{t \in [0, 1]} |g(t) - h(t)|
$$

for all $ g(t)$, $ h(t) \in C[0, 1] $.

I evaluated $f(t)$ and wrote this:

$$
d(Fg(t), Fh(t)) = \sup_{t \in [0, 1]}\left|\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} [g(3t) - h(3t)],& 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{3}\\\ \frac{1}{4}\left[(g(3 t) - h(3 t))(3 t - 1) + (g(3t - 2) - h(3t - 2))(2 - 3t )\right], & \frac{1}{3} < t\leq \frac{2}{3}\\\ \frac{1}{2}[g(3t - 2) - h(3t - 2)],&\frac{2}{3} < t \leq 1 \end{cases}\right|
$$

It can be simplified:

$$
d(Fg(t), Fh(t)) = \sup_{t \in [0, 1]}\left|\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} [g(t) - h(t)],& 0 \leq t \leq 1\\\ \frac{1}{4}\left[(g(3 t) - h(3 t))(3 t - 1) + (g(3t - 2) - h(3t - 2))(2 - 3t )\right], & \frac{1}{3} < t\leq \frac{2}{3}\\\ \frac{1}{2}[g(t) - h(t)],&0 < t \leq 1 \end{cases}\right|
$$

If there was a way to show that

$$
\sup_{t \in [0, 1]}\left|\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} [g(t) - h(t)],& 0 \leq t \leq 1\\\ \frac{1}{4}\left[(g(3 t) - h(3 t))(3 t - 1) + (g(3t - 2) - h(3t - 2))(2 - 3t )\right], & \frac{1}{3} < t\leq \frac{2}{3}\\\ \frac{1}{2}[g(t) - h(t)],&0 < t \leq 1 \end{cases}\right| \leq \sup_{t \in [0, 1]}\left|\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} [g(t) - h(t)],& 0 \leq t \leq 1\\\ \alpha [g(t) - h(t)], & 0 < t\leq 1\\\ \frac{1}{2}[g(t) - h(t)],&0 < t \leq 1 \end{cases}\right| \leq \\\ \sup_{t \in [0, 1]} |g(t) - h(t)|
$$

I would consider this solved, however I can't find a way to transform the long second expression (let's call it $H$). One problem is that $H(\frac{2}{3})$ is $  \frac{1}{4} (g(2) - h(2))$, and $ 2 \not\in [0, 1]$.

How can I deal with this? Am I on the right track? If not, is there any other way to prove it?

Comment: Where is the contraction constant?

Comment: But you have no such $k$ above.

Comment: All I'm saying is you didn't define a contraction map properly in the statement of the problem. Where is $k$ in the bit following "the proof will need to show that"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You've shown $\sup_{[0,1/3]} |Fg(t)=Fh(t)| \le (1/2)\sup_{[0,1]} |g(t)-h(t)|.$ Same for $[2/3,1].$ So far so good.

Now, what to do about the annoying middle third? You've made a mistake somewhere on this part. Let's get out of computation mode and try this: If $y(t)$ is linear on $[a,b],$ then $$\sup_{t\in [a,b]}|y(t)| = \max (|y(a)|, |y(b)|).$$ I'm thinking here of $y$ as the difference of your two linear functions on $[1/3,2/3].$

Comment: You have formulas for $Fg,Fh$ at $1/3,2/3.$ Subtract those to get the values of $y$ at those points.